# Jquery/JS - AJAX response if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I'm new to JS and don't know how to test this IF condition.

If the JSON response has content = false, then this popupSubmit function must be called.

Please assist in checking and letting me know where the error is if the condition is written.

Thanks

```js
{
    "id": "4974635f-514e-4d26-8170-ae77c984e8ab",
    "content": "true",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "redirect": null
}


var checkID = $('#id-no').val();
var getDomainName = window.location.origin;
$.ajax({
        url: getDomainName + '/.rest/stripe/v1/checkID?id=' + checkID,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function success(response) {
          //response = JSON.parse(response);
          $.each(response, function (i, v) {
            console.log(i.content);
            if (i.content == 'false') {
              popupSubmit();
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Hi may I know what's the error / issue?

Comment: Your API response is one object so it's not clear why you're iterating over it.

Comment: What is the `popupSubmit()` function for? Please add more context to the codebase or replicate it with https://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: `$.each(response, function (i, v) {` — You've got a single object. There's nothing to loop over. This loop appears to be your problem. Remove it.

Comment: As pointed out, if your JSON is really just that single object you've shown, there is o need to iterate over it.  Simply test `if (response.content === 'false') {` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(response.content == 'false'){
   popupSubmit();
}
```